# ¿En html se puede tener un parrafo y ajustar un input switch a la derecha en la misma linea?

Tags: html, css, input, switch

Quisiera saber si se puede ajustar a sus respectivas esquinas ya use float-right pero no mueve el input a la derecha

Asi es como lo tengo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera que se viera asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### este es mi código

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-section">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="card-text">ACCIÓN RAPIDA, ACEPTAR TODOS LOS PERMISOS PARA EL MÓDULO SELECCIONADO
          <input type="checkbox" name="switchery" id="switchery " class="switchery master" value="" idcontrol="1" style="display: none;" data-switchery="true">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

Comment: no sé en que posicion quieres que quede exactamente el input, te puede servir un margin-left:100vh.

Comment: Semánticamente hablando, no es correcto colocar un elemento `<input>` dentro de un elemento `<p>`. El elemento `<p>` debe contener elementos de tipo [*redacción*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/categorias_de_contenido#Contenido_de_redacción). Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Lo que te recomiendo hacer es agregarle la propiedad `display: flex;` a tu parrafo, y despues agregarle la propiedad `justify-content: space-between;` esto hara que deje un espacio entre en medio de tus 2 elementos, el texto y tu input.

2.- Tu codigo CSS quedaria de la siguiete manera:

```
.card-text{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

3.- Te muestro un ejemplo practico para que puedas observar el resultado:

```css
.card-text{
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #f2f0f5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-section">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="card-text">ACCIÓN RAPIDA, ACEPTAR TODOS LOS PERMISOS PARA EL MÓDULO SELECCIONADO
          <input type="checkbox" name="switchery" id="switchery " class="switchery master" value="" idcontrol="1" data-switchery="true">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

4.- Hubiera sido genial que compartieras tus estilos del formulario, para poder dar una respuesta mas acertada.